# Yii2 Tesseract OCR failing with proc_open(): CreateProcess > failed, error code - 5

Tags: php, yii2, tesseract

I am working with Tesseract to extract contents from image or even in pdf file using Yii2 plugin thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR.However,during my testing Im having problem extracting the content from the Image.

Here is my code:

```
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('C:\Users\users\Desktop\FolderName\text.png');  
$tesseract->executable('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR');  
$tesseract->run();
```

Here is the error:

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException   proc_open(): CreateProcess
> failed, error code - 5

Thank you!

Comment: `Error code 5` is a permissions issue. You need to ensure that php has access to both those files.

Comment: Its nowworking, I forgot to add tesseract.exe just like this   ->executable('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe')

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same like this

> $tesseract = new TesseractOCR('C:\Users\users\Desktop\FolderName\text.png');
> $tesseract->executable('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'');
> $tesseract->run();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).